# django dynamically loading a static file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am trying to send a static link to a download button. The static link results in a views.py function and will be returned as a dict.

```
in views.py:
def some_fct(request):
    handling the request
    return render(request,'site.html',{'processed_request': 'name_of_static_file'})
```

I tried to locate the data in a seperate div and change the href with:

```
<div id="data">{{processed_request}}<\div>
<a href="" id="download"><button class="download_btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button></a>

<script>
let file = document.getElementbyId('data').innerHTML; 
let file_static = "{% static '${file}' %}"   
document.getElementById('download').setAttribute("href",file_static);
</script>
```

which leads to the console.log

```
https://..../static/%24%7Bfile%7D
```

instead of

```
https://..../static/name_of_static_file
```

How can I access the static_file?

Comment: If you know static file name in the view then you don't need JS and can satisfy your needs with django template tags only. It also smells like reinventing a media files concept.

Comment: thank you, I am quite new to django and just did not know where to look at...for those who are stuck at the same point:
just use the variable name in the tag: "{% static processed_request %}"
now it is quite obvious.
Sorry for bothering and thanks again,
Cheers